# Fuzzy Wine Ontology SPARQL - HighPriceForWine

Tags: sparql, ontology, protege, fuzzy

I use `FuzzyWine1.0.owl`, I want to display 1 type of drink from `HighPriceForWine` which has been processed on the **Fuzzy Plugin** tab in **Protege**, I have tried typing queries, but all types of wine then appear.

[image: screenshot]

Actually, what should I type in the SPARQL Query? Has anyone ever done that?

```
PREFIX wine: <http://www.w3.org/TR/2003/PR-owl-guide-20031209/wine#>
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>
PREFIX xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
SELECT ?HighPriceFoWine ?price
WHERE  {?HighPriceForWine wine:hasPrice ?price }
```

Before, I have tried making the `Select` command with a `filter`, but none of the results appear. For `HighPriceForWine` it has been annotated in the Fuzzy Ontology plugin in Protege

Comment: Ehm, do you know the difference between a variable and an IRI? `?HighPriceForWine` is obviously a variable which results in bindings for all entities that match the pattern, i.e. have a value for `wine:hasPrice`. You should clearly start with a SPARQL tutorial, and then try `SELECT ?price
WHERE  {wine:HighPriceForWine wine:hasPrice ?price }` - if you also want the wine itself do `SELECT ?wine ?price
WHERE  {?wine wine:hasPrice ?price FILTER(?wine = wine:HighPriceForWine) }`

Comment: @AKSW I have tried making the "Select" command with a "filter" like that, but none of the results appear. For "HighPriceForWine" it has been annotated in the Fuzzy Ontology plugin in Protege.

Comment: I checked the ontology and wondering what exactly you want to query for. In the ontology itself, `HighPriceForWine` is a datatype, isn't it? So, your query wouldn't work anyways. `hasPrice` connect individuals with prices. So, what do you want to get out of the ontology?

Comment: @AKSW From the Fuzzy Wine ontology, I want to display one of the most expensive types of wine from the many wines in the FuzzyWine1.0.owl.

Comment: Ok, but how do you define "most expensive type of wine" - I mean, you have the ontology opened in Protege, so based on which fact the SPARQL query should return what exactly? Which particular classes or individuals do you expect based on which assumption?

Comment: By the way, using the SPARQL query together with Fuzzy reasoning - if you need this - does not work.

Comment: @AKSW Yes right, I tried using a SPARQL query along with Fuzzy reasoning.
I am a newbie in Fuzzy Ontology,
and I'm still confused about how to show the results of the Fuzzy Owl plugin that was added to the protege.